# Fetch Data with If Else condition Using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query:

```
select a,b,c,d from Table1 where a in ('');
```

The query gives me output as follows:

```
a    b    c      d
1    A    1e@c   i-1
2    B    #3ht   i-2
3    A    1e@c   Null
4    C    1e@c
```

Now I want to apply **IF condition** for those records where I have `d` as Null or Blank.

I want to check in whole database if I could find any `d` value corresponding to `b` value or `c` value and show it in other column e.

Desired Output:

```
a    b    c      d     e
1    A    1e@c   i-1   
2    B    #3ht   i-2
3    A    1e@c   Null  i-1
4    C    1e@c         i-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d,
       CASE 
          WHEN t1.d IS NULL OR t1.d = '' 
          THEN  (SELECT t2.d
                FROM Table1 AS t2
                WHERE t2.c = t1.c LIMIT 1) 
       END AS e 
FROm Table1 AS t1
WHERE t1.a IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

If you have more than one matches you can use `LIMIT 1` to arbitrarily select one of those. Otherwise use some predicate to select the desired matching record.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a4d05/6)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SELECT IFNULL(d,'1-1') as e` or `SELECT IF((d = ''),'1-1','') as e` or `SELECT IF((d IS NULL) || (d = ''),'1-1','') as e`

Comment: the proper way to do so it to use a case statement which allows your code to work on any db

Comment: @Steven agreed with you but I answered as per the question statement.

Comment: @VikasChaudhary That is not the question statement, question statement is how to query using `b` or `c` where we are getting Null or Blank while querying `a`.

Comment: @Roy1245 It seems i didn't get through the question properly but still it can be achieved with IF statement only without using CASE in mysql
IF((d IS NULL || d = ''),'1-1',d )  AS e

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, CASE WHEN D IS NULL OR D='' THEN 'i-1' ELSE '' END AS E
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE WHEN "Condition" THEN "do this"`.
It is BASICALLY the equivalent to a if statement in SQL.